# Is there any way at all to skip the setup process after factory reset on an android phone with an unresponsive touch screen?

Tags: factory-reset, touchscreen, broken-screen, huawei-honor-6

I have an android phone with an unresponsive touchscreen. I, at first, thought it might be a software problem and did a factory reset with power button and volume up button as given [here](http://www.hardreset.info/devices/huawei/huawei-honor-6/).

The reset went fine and i rebooted the phone. It rebooted to the initial setup screen where you have to select a language. Now, the touch screen is still not working. Probably a hardware defect. And i am stuck in this screen unable to proceed.

*So, is there something, anything i can do about it without needing to take to a repair shop.?*

The phone is an honour h6

Comment: Question is, what does it help you to skip the wizard if you cannot use the screen at all? You'll have to see a repair shop anyway. And as you already did a factory-reset, there's no data to rescue I guess? // Pointer: Take a look at our [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info), you'll find it useful (e.g. the "second use" section).

Answer (score 1):

Since you're talking about a mobile phone (and I'm assuming that you're not rooted), then, unfortunately, no there is no way to skip the setup screens if the touch screen no longer works.

I was thinking that maybe you could pair an external bluetooth device (mouse and/or keyboard) but you have to get past the setup screen to do that.

You could try using an OTG cable with a USB mouse and/or keyboard.

Answer (score -2):

I know this question is an year old, but I also faced this problem recently on my Lenovo Vibe phone. For me, tapping multiple times (may be 4-5 times) on the screen did the trick.

Comment: You know what **unresponsive touch screen** means right? As per your answer it seems, your phone is _quite responsive_